# How to get HttpEntity from SimpleHttpResponse using Apache httpclient5

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am trying to migrate from **httpclient4** to **httpclient5**.

I use `CloseableHttpAsyncClient` to execute the requests.

when using **httpclient4** `httpClient.execute()` expects `HttpRequestUri` as the first argument, and `FutureCallable<httpResponse>` as the second argument.

But in **httpclient5** when you call `httpClient.execute()` it expects `SimpleHttpRequest` as the first parameter, and `FutureCallable<SimpleHttpResponse>` as the second parameter.

The problem is that I’m using `response.getEntity()` in `completed` method of the future, and i have to use the `HttpEntity` for valid reasons. But `SimpleHttpResponse` doesn’t have `getEntity()` method.

Is there any way to get `HttpEntity` from `SimpleHttpResponse`?

Another way to solve this is to use `ClassicHttpRespose` instead of `SimpleHttpResponse`, because it has `getEntity()` method. The problem is that `execute()` method doesn’t receive it as a valid argument.

For conclusion is there a way to get the entity from `SimpleHttpResponse` **or** to use `execute` on `ClassicHttpResponse`?

Comment: Wouldn't getting the entity be [getting the body](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/async/methods/SimpleHttpResponse.html#getBody())?

Comment: No because I am using it as `HttpEntity`, and `getBody()` returns `SimpleBody`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that's the type it returns. I'm talking about the logical operation you're doing (getting the content of a response)

Comment: The problem is that I use `entity.getContent()` (in a critical place) which returns `InputStream`. So I must use a solution with `InputStream`

Comment: What, you mean like `InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(shr.getBodyBytes());`? ;)

Comment: This is what I did eventually, but I need to change a lot of code with it. I hope it will work thank you

Comment: Did you find any solution? I also need `HttpEntity` from `SimpleHttpResponse` because i need to prepare `GzipDecompressingEntity` which expects `HttpEntity` only...